# How to create a alert by using array to do compare

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel

1, I want to create a js as a reminder when my unit_balance is lower than 20.

2, 1st What i do is get each of unit_balance then i write a function to do compare < 20

3, if true then show alert , if not just ignore the alert

4, the code still error because i put all my unit_balance all higher then 20 also gv me alert

5, can give me some idea to do this? Im not good in js.

6, Please helps me. thank you

```html
<body onload="myFunction()">
```

```js
<script>
var unit_balance = [
  @foreach ($bike as $value)
      ['{{ $value->unit_balance }}']
  @endforeach
];

function myFunction(){
  if(unit_balance < 20, true){
  alert("Some of unit left is less than 20. Please restock immediately!");
  } 
}
</script>
```

Comment: `unit_balance < 20` makes little sense, when `unit_balance` is an array … You need to loop over the content of that array, and then perform this comparison for the individual items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you unit_balance is array then you need to filter the value and check the length of the array

```
<body onload="myFunction()">

  <script>
   var unit_balance = [
     20, 30 
    ];

  function myFunction(){
       var totalLessThan20 = unit_balance.filter(unit => unit <=20 );
       if(totalLessThan20.length) {
        alert("Some of unit left is less than 20. Please restock 
      immediately!");
     }
  }
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6ynxz27f/1/

Comment: try this `
$data = '';
foreach($bike as $value) {
    $data .= $value->unit_balance.",";
}
`

and in javascript variable `var unit_balance = [
    rtrim($data, ",")
    ];`